# How to insert meta tags in my webpage body

Tags: html

The software I am using for my website doesn't give me access to the page Heads. I want to use meta tags to improve my search engine ratings. How can I insert them innthe body of the pages?

Comment: META tags don't go in the body. It's not valid W3 HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Um, what software are you using for your webpage?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp